# Python: add elements from second list based on matched values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, search, insert

I have two lists:

```
survey_points = [ [101,123.456,101.234,99.234] , [102,88.243,211.245,100.834] , [103,13.556,134.234,99.234] , [104,12.345,95.342,99.121] ]
survey_points_attributes = [ [101,305] , [102,306] , [103,305] , [104,308] , [105,310] , [106,307] , [107,306] , [108,305] , [109,305] , [110,307] ]
```

List 'survey_points' contains point measurements. Format "Point number, distance, angle horizontal, angle vertical"
List 'survey_points_attributes' contains point attributes/codes. Format "Point number, point attribute/code"

Using the survey_points list I'd like to add the point attribute/code between point number and distance. The search-key between the two would be the point number. E.g. The first point 101 in survey_list is 101, now 101 shows attribute '305' in survey_points_attributes. This '305' value shall now be inserted just after 101 in survey_list
How can I achieve this?

The output/result should look like this:

```
    survey_points = [ [101,305,123.456,101.234,99.234] , [102,306,88.243,211.245,100.834] , [103,305,13.556,134.234,99.234] , [104,308,12.345,95.342,99.121] ]
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
mapping = dict(survey_points_attributes)

survey_points = [
    [p, mapping[p], *rest] if p in mapping else [p, *rest]
    for p, *rest in survey_points
]
print(survey_points)
```

Prints:

```
[
    [101, 305, 123.456, 101.234, 99.234],
    [102, 306, 88.243, 211.245, 100.834],
    [103, 305, 13.556, 134.234, 99.234],
    [104, 308, 12.345, 95.342, 99.121],
]
```

---

OR: if the point ID is not found in attributes, insert `None` instead:

```py
survey_points = [[p, mapping.get(p), *rest] for p, *rest in survey_points]
```

Comment: Hi Andrej, this one works great! Especially the the insert None if no code is defined! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
survey_points = [ [101,123.456,101.234,99.234] , [102,88.243,211.245,100.834] , [103,13.556,134.234,99.234] , [104,12.345,95.342,99.121] ]
survey_points_attributes = [ [101,305] , [102,306] , [103,305] , [104,308] , [105,310] , [106,307] , [107,306] , [108,305] , [109,305] , [110,307] ]

for point in survey_points:
    for attribute in survey_points_attributes:
        if point[0] == attribute[0]:
            point.insert(1,attribute[1])

print(survey_points)
```

Comment: Hi luke, works. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use a `dict` to store the attributes, then use the `dict` to update the `list`.
survey_points = [ [101,123.456,101.234,99.234] , [102,88.243,211.245,100.834] , [103,13.556,134.234,99.234] , [104,12.345,95.342,99.121] ]
survey_points_attributes = [ [101,305] , [102,306] , [103,305] , [104,308] , [105,310] , [106,307] , [107,306] , [108,305] , [109,305] , [110,307] ]

## create a dict from the attribute points

attributes = dict(survey_points_attributes)

## update the first item in the point list with the attribute

for point in survey_points:
point[0:0] = [attributes.get(point[0], 'NA')]

print

Comment: Hi Sh_gosha, thank you. Almost perfect. The code is being inserted prior to the point number. But I can see how to fix it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What do you think?

```
survey_points = [ [101,123.456,101.234,99.234] , [102,88.243,211.245,100.834] , [103,13.556,134.234,99.234] , [104,12.345,95.342,99.121] ]
survey_points_attributes = [ [101,305] , [102,306] , [103,305] , [104,308] , [105,310] , [106,307] , [107,306] , [108,305] , [109,305] , [110,307] ]

a = []

for i in range(0, len(survey_points[:])):
    a.append([survey_points[i][0], survey_points_attributes[i][1], survey_points[i][1], survey_points[i][2], survey_points[i][3]]) 

survey_points = a

print(f"survey_points = {survey_points[:]}")
```

survey_points = [[101, 305, 123.456, 101.234, 99.234], [102, 306, 88.243, 211.245, 100.834], [103, 305, 13.556, 134.234, 99.234], [104, 308, 12.345, 95.342, 99.121]]

Comment: Hi Joell, works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
result_list = []
for item in zip(survey_points, survey_points_attributes):
   item[0].insert(1,item[1][1])
   result_list.append(item[0])
```

Comment: Hi Sahin, works. Thank you